# Android Hierarchy Viewer is not showing performance indicators for a view

Tags: android

I am working with Android 2.2. While checking the views using HierarchyViewer, no performance indicators are being displayed. It shows 'n/a' agianst each of the three measures. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6):

You need Android 2.3 or later to use this feature.

Comment: I have the same issue with Android 4.0.

Comment: @FabianZeindl to see the three measures select your root view and click the button with description "Obtain layout times for tree rooted at selected node", which has to be on the top of the Hierarchy View.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using one of the Genymotion emulators, I had the same problem. The performance indicators would not show up when I clicked on the tri-colored layout times button on the upper right.

But when I switched to an emulator using API 17 instead, then it worked. So not sure which of all the emulators work and which don't, but just keep in mind it could be the emulator you are currently using, so try switching to a different one. To switch, I had to restart the **hierarchyviewer**, and reload the views.